Generation of abstract reasoning puzzles
I'm trying to automatically generate abstract reasoning puzzles. My problem is, that I want to ensure that they "make sense", i.e. there is only one logical correct solution.
Suppose, that each instance consists of one or multiple examples, each with a a setup and a solution, and one final setup, to which the correct solution must be deduced.
The exact structure and presentation of these puzzles should not matter.
What I want to do is randomly generate some setups and corresponding calculated solutions, based on some rules/patterns. For each setup and solution, I want to calculate a set of properties, which are relevant or related to the problem (these are pre-defined for each template). These properties could be for example:
Example 1: Setup(PropertyA=0, PropertyB=2), Solution(PropertyX=1, PropertyY=2)
Example 2: Setup(PropertyA=1, PropertyB=3), Solution(PropertyX=0, PropertyY=3)
Each template defines a subset of the properties of the setup and a function (can be assumed to be selected from a small known set) to map them to a subset of the properties of the solution. This defines, the correct solution.
My goal now is to ensure that

The solution for the final setup can be derived by logical reasoning from the examples with a given solution
No property defined by the template can be replaced with a property not in the subset and still arrive at the same expected solution
No alternative solution can be derived from the examples with a given solution considering all the properties

I have two concrete questions to takle this problem:
a) What would be good fit for a logic formalism and encoding to present and reason about a problem like this?
b) Are you aware of any tool support, that could automatically find the answers to 1., 2. and 3.?
Here is a full example (of what I don't want to happen):
Task: "Count the objects" (not revealed to the player)

Two randomly generated hints:

Setup 1: An image of 3 red objects (Properties: blue=0, red=3, objects=3)
Solution 1: the number 3 (Property: num=3)

Setup 2: An image of 1 red object (Properties: blue=0, red=1, objects=1)
Solution 2: the number 1 (Property: num=1)

And the challenge to solve by the player:

Challenge Setup: An image of 1 blue and 1 red object (Properties: blue=1, red=1, objects=2)
Expected solution: the number 2 (Property: num=2)

Setup1/Solution1 and Setup2/Solution2 allow both conclusions,
that the result is either the total number of objects or the number of red objects.
Thus they are bad examples to properly describe the task "count the objects".


It's hard to understand what you mean without a more concrete example of a puzzle. But it sounds like you're talking about the kind of so-called logic puzzles that are actually "complete the pattern by making an educated guess about what the problem author was thinking" tasks, which can't be solved by pure deduction since any given data can be described by infinitely many different rules.

Yes, the general case is certainly not solvable, but with a restricted set of properties and a restricted set of possible mapping functions, it should be solvable, as it inherently cannot have infinite solutions. My idea is to root out as many as possible "obvious" wrong guesses about what the author was thinking by ensuring, that the examples provide counter examples for the theory.

The folks at Puzzling.SE may have some insights and/or advice.

An example of what you have in mind would help a lot.

I edited the question to include an example.

The solution could also be red + 2 blue = 3, why is it excluded ? Or more precisely, what defines the set of possible calculations for the conclusion?

It is not necessarily excluded. I just used the simplest formula for my example. Whether red + 2*blue could also be a solution (in the context of this algorithm), depends on the chosen set of possible mapping functions f. My point is, that these are exactly the kinds of situations I want to able to detect! (if the relevant function is in the selected set)

The problem is that it is really hard to define what is a "simple formula". Either you do a puzzle with well-described rules, like sudoku, and then you can try creating algorithms to generate puzzles with a unique solution and interesting mechanism in the logic. Or you have a puzzle relying on some arbitrary notion of simplicity, like sequence pattern puzzles, but then you can't do it algorithmically since it requires an arbitrary judgment to evaluate the soundness of the puzzle.

Here's a way to formalize what you're describing:
A puzzle template consists of a set $X$ (of all possible inputs or "setups"), a set $Y$ (of all possible outputs), and a set $\mathcal R$ of binary relations over $X$ and $Y$, which we think of as the possible/allowed "rules". Note that functions are relations, so a rule can be a function $X\to Y$.
A puzzle instance is a set $E\subset X\times Y$ (of example input-output pairs) and a "challenge input" $\hat x\in X$.
A valid response to a puzzle instance $(E,\hat x)$ is an output value $\hat y\in Y$ such that $(E\cup\{(\hat x,\hat y)\})\subseteq R$ for some $R\in\mathcal R$. That is, $\hat y$ is a valid response if there is a rule $R$ which is obeyed by each example pair as well as the pair $(\hat x,\hat y)$.
For an instance to be solvable and unambiguous, it should admit exactly one valid response. (This means that every rule consistent with $E$ gives the same response to $\hat x$. To be more strict, you could require that there is only one such rule.)
Now it should be straightforward to programmatically generate puzzles.

First generate the sets $X,Y,\mathcal R$. This is where you can encode your notion of "properties" and enumerate the allowed rules.

To generate an instance, pick a rule $R$ and a challenge input $\hat x$ compatible with $R$, and then (at random or by whatever heuristics you want) add pairs from $R$ to a hint set $E$ until the desired condition is met. You could do this by maintaining a set of rules compatible with $E$, adding elements to $E$ at each step in order to invalidate a possible rule until only $R$ remains.


